# Can't connect to heroku postgres from heroku local using node sample

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I followed the steps at:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction

When I ran heroku local it couldn't connect - I saw that it was using the process.env.DATABASE_URL and got it to my local .env file using:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local

But it still wouldn't connect, I've added a console.log to see the error:

"error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "62.90.xxx.yyy", user "username", database "password", SSL off"

What now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searches it turns out that added 'pg.defaults.ssl = true' solves the problem for me while allowing me to stay as close as possible to the sample provided by Heroku.

Here is my code

```
const cool = require('cool-ascii-faces');
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

const pg = require('pg');
pg.defaults.ssl = true; //this is it!!!

express()
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
....
```

Answer (score 0):

A neat solution would be enabling SSL only for the Heroku server connection. For that add `dialectOptions.ssl=true` to Heroku environment in `config.json` file:

```
  {
"production": {
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL",
    "dialectOptions": { "ssl": true },
    "logging": false
  }
```